# Is there a way to apply different colored masks on images?

Tags: python, image, pycharm, detection, opencv

I would like to add different colored masks to a specific class of objects. I'm using `detectron2` to detect people in the image, then  I need to draw colored mask on them (e.g black, white, blurred, gray segmented masks), which is mean 4 or 5 output for single image.

I've tried the metadata color mode, and it was not the expected result that I'm looking for.